# How can I call a web method from .net compact framework without getting an exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, exception, compact-framework

When trying to call a web method from the .net compact framework I get the following (useless) exception in the debugger:

> An error message cannot be displayed
>   because an optional resource assembly
>   containing it cannot be found

I get a slightly differently worded error on the mobile device, but it effectively says the same thing.

The web service works as I've tested it in normal .net

I'm using compact framework v2.0, but I'm also tried creating a simple project in v.3.5 to test my problem - I've spent a while trying to solve this - [most solutions](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Windows_Mobile-_PocketPC-_WinCE/Q_23005473.html) & .Net tell me install the cab file called (for v3.5) `netcfv35.messages.en.wn.cab` (and for v2.0 either) `system_sr_enu.cab` and `system_sr_enu_wm.cab`

First I don't know why when I call this web method I am getting an exception in the compact framework when it works on normal .net (it only returns a simple object that has some string and integer properties). Further to that, I can't work out what is wrong as the exception doesn't display properly. Does anyone have any information that would help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/martijnh/fixing-exception-messages-on-the-net-compact-framework-3-5)

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Fair play, I was suspicious, but it worked! Do you know how to do this in compact framework 2?